# How can I design a database for ordering food as a waiter

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, ssms

I have these tables:

```
 User (Username PK, password)
    Order (OrderId PK,date,nettotal,userid FK_User_Order)
    FoodItem(FoodID PK,Price)
    OrderDetails(DetailId PK,OrderId FK_Order_OrderDetails,FoodID FK_Food_OrderDetails,quantity,totalsum)
```

OrderDetails have the details when a user is ordering food, with each row representing one of the items.

Per example:

If a user ordered 2 pizzas (Food Id=1) and 1 burger (FoodId=2)
I would expect my OrderDetails to be filled with 2 rows like this:

```
1st row: DetailID=1,OrderId=1,FoodId=1,quantity=2,price=500
2nd row: DetailID=1,OrderId=1,FoodId=2,quantity=1,price=250
```

I need them to have the same OrderId so I can know they belong to one order, but if it is the first time there is no rows in the Order table. How can I design this so they create  an order row like this:

```
OrderId=1,date=SYSDATE,nettotal=500+250,userid=1)
```

Comment: A Normalised approach would have a table for your orders and then a different table for the items in your order, with a foreign key back to the order table.

Comment: That's what I did, I have the Order with OrderId and OrderDetails which represent the items in that order with OrderId as a foreign key @Larnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is psuedo SQL here, but what you need is the `OUTPUT` clause when you perform the `INSERT`. If we *assume* you have scalar parameters for the order itself and a table type parameter for the food items, then you're SQL is going to look a little like this:

```
DECLARE @Order table (OrderID int)

INSERT INTO dbo.OrderTable (OrderDate, UserID) --NetTotal shouldn't really be stroed, as it can be derived from the order details
OUTPUT inserted.OrderID
INTO @Order (OrderID)
SELECT GETDATE(), @UserID;

INSERT INTO dbo.OrderItems (ItemID, OrderID, Quantity)
SELECT I.ItemID,
       O.OrderID,
       I.Quantity
FROM @Items I --YOur table type parameter
     CROSS JOIN @Order O;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using an noSQL database might be of help in case of this structure, as they'll provide you a more flexible system to deal with in case of scalability
2. For transactions of your order which is **OrderDetails**, you can use MySQL or any other RDBMS.
3. If you are asking just about the design, then you can refer to foreign key and primary key constraints, try maintaining the same among the databases during the operations.
4. You'll have to normalise the parameters among these collections/tables, this will give you more controlled and systematic environment for further development
5. If you need to have all of these details in MySQL then again you need to follow above points...

You can also refer to existing projects for reference, this will give you a more clear idea.

You can refer to following link for a basic schema structure for reference :
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Database-Schema-for-the-Restaurant-Ordering-System_fig4_323230406

If your doubt is different then this... then please mention in comment.